Change an image on HTML Canvas after every refresh
I am learning how to use HTML and JavaScript and am fairly new/beginner.  I have learned recently through my class being able to create a canvas an to draw images or shapes.  I created the below but one of the tasks is to create a randomness within the canvas, I decided to try and change the heart image to different ones but am unable to try to apply the math code, I know you may need to use math floor and math random but am unsure how to go about placing the code on the canvas, any help would be greatly appreciated.
The ones I have googled through show arrays as well and I even found the below, but its for background images, and what I am trying to do is change an image placed on the canvas:
Below is my code, I have shortened as it has other elements:


var myCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var myContext = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
var obstacle = new Image();
obstacle.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f1/Heart_coraz%C3%B3n.svg/160px-Heart_coraz%C3%B3n.svg.png";
obstacle.onload = function() {
  myContext.drawImage(obstacle, 50, 50);
}

function changeBackgroundImage() {
  const images = [
    "url('https://placehold.co/600x400/orange/white')",
    "url('https://placehold.co/600x400/yellow/teal')",
    "url('https://placehold.co/600x400/red/green')"
  ];
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = images[randomIndex];
}
window.onload = changeBackgroundImage;
<canvas id="canvas1" width="1000" height="900" style="border: dotted 3px #001219;background-color:#E9D8A6;">Your browser does not support canvas></canvas>




Please visit Markdown help

Also you can get images for the snippet from https://placehold.co/

And validate your HTML at https://validator.w3.org/

You don't seem to be using your randomised image in the canvas logic, you are always setting obstacle.src = "(heart src)"

They do use it for the document background, so the random works.

If you need to change location of image, you need to change this code: myContext.drawImage(obstacle, 50, 50); 1 as first number is position in X plain and second is in Y plain
You may also add restrictions to not draw image outside visible place (not added)
To get random number use Math.random()


var myCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var myContext = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
var obstacle = new Image();
obstacle.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f1/Heart_coraz%C3%B3n.svg/160px-Heart_coraz%C3%B3n.svg.png";
obstacle.onload = function() {
  let randX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
  let randY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);

  myContext.drawImage(obstacle, randX, randY);
}

// ...
<canvas id="canvas1" width="1000" height="900" style="border: dotted 3px #001219;background-color:#E9D8A6;">Your browser does not support canvas></canvas>



